# custom post type categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
<ul id="thumbs" class="portfolio">
                        <?php

                    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
                    'showposts' => 8,
                    'post_type' => array('portfolioo'),
                    $catIDs = get_cat_ID( $cat_name='Graphic design' ),
                    $catIDs .= ',' . get_cat_ID( $cat_name='Icons' ),
                    $catIDs .= ',' . get_cat_ID( $cat_name='web-design' ),

                    )
                    );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
                    ?>

                    <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                    <li class="item-thumbs col-lg-3 design" data-id="id-0" data-type="<?php echo $catIDs; ?>">
                    <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                    <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Portfolio name" href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
                    <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                    <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                    </a>
                    <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                    <img src="<?php echo $catIDs; ?>" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                    </li>
                    <!-- End Item Project -->

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
```

I have a custom post type name portfolio and in it three categories icon,web,graphic and all have images in it. How can i show that images related to particular category in

based on loop in wordpress ?

Comment: That doesn't make people want to reply faster... But is "category" a custom taxonomy or the native WordPress categories that you attached to your post type? You WP_Query is all wrong... should produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some weird stuff in your code, but I think you need to fix this; unless you are using a custom taxonomy... then you need "tax_query" instead of "category__in".

```
  $loop = new WP_Query( 
    array(
      'showposts' => 8,
      'post_type' => array('portfolioo'),
      'category__in' => array( get_cat_ID( 'Graphic design' ), get_cat_ID( 'Icons' ), get_cat_ID( $cat_name='web-design' ) )
    )
  );
```